# How to send email to Admin in Magento 2.4 when order status change ( Cancel and Hold )

Tags: magento2, admin, orders, email, order-status

I want to send Email in Magento 2 when order status change in ( Cancel and Hold )

My current code is :

```
<?php

namespace Hlemail\Customemail\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderCommentSender;

class OrderSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
{

protected $orderCommentSender;

public function __construct(
    OrderCommentSender $orderCommentSender
)
{
    $this->orderCommentSender = $orderCommentSender;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    if ($order->getState() == 'canceled') {
        $this->orderCommentSender->send($order, true);
    }
}
}
```

How to send email to Admin.
Any help is appriciated.

Comment: This maybe work for you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123140/magento2-how-to-send-order-status-change-email-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

Refer `sales_order_save_after` event.

In observer, you can get the state of order:

> **Observer/SalesOrderAfterSave.php**

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    if ($order instanceof \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel) {
       if($order->getState() == 'canceled' || $order->getState() == 'closed') {
            //Your code here
       }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

If you want to transform or update the data then you should use the plugin.

> **etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="order_state_plugin"
                type="Vendor\Module\Model\OrderStatePlugin"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

> **Model\Plugin\OrderStatePlugin.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class OrderStatePlugin
{
/**
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $result
 * @return mixed
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function afterSave(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject,
    $result
) {
    if($result->getState() == Order::STATE_COMPLETE) {
        ......
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Hamendra i need to send new mail template when status is changed .

Comment: You can send, just create an helper file & add code there call helper method in observer file.

Comment: @Prits use this link to send email https://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/sending-custom-emails-using-custom-module-in-magento-2/

Comment: by using the above answer